# create new dataframe for duplicate value

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

im trying to create new dataframe for duplicate value from column called "NOMORCIF"

```
[1]: https://imgur.com/8bKnYd0 "column i mentioned"
```

i have tried this following code :

```
df['duplicate']=df['NOMORCIF'].apply(pd.value_counts)
```

df['duplicate'] is supposed to be new dataframe with duplicate value from df['NOMORCIF']

but i get these following error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score -1):

just incase anyone have the same struggle, i already solved this

```
df['freq'] = df.groupby('NOMORCIF')['NOMORCIF'].transform('count')
```

df.head()